# Best practice for storing and retrieving a list of strings in a single JSON key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'd like to determine the best practice for storing and retrieving a simple list into a single JSON key.

Let's assume I have 5 friends:

```
bob, joe, peter, susan, & tiffany
```

Say I've got a larger JSON collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "title":"my title",
    "description":"my description about this collection"
}
```

Now if I wanted to add this list of friends to my collection under the key "friends", I would probably structure it like this:

```
{
    "title":"my title",
    "description":"my description about this collection"
    "friends":[
        "bob",
        "joe",
        "peter",
        "susan",
        "tiffany"
    ]
}
```

One of the biggest challenges I've faced doing it this way is that you can't use some of the built in javascript or php array functions.

On the other hand, storing an unknown number of objects in a key:value paired array would be equally unmanageable.

If someone could explain best way to store a list of strings in JSON I'd be indebted. Are there easier ways to search and access the array data?

Comment: what do you mean you can't use JS array searching functions?  `myObj.friends.indexOf('joe') === 1`

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf`? `array_search`?

Comment: What do you mean, "you can't use JavaScript or php array searching functions"?  You certainly can. *edit* ha ha wow

Comment: also, investigate "jsonpath" - it's very good for traversing JS objects

Comment: Easier than what?  I don't see any attempt to search or access an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in the most normalized format *unless* there is good reason to do otherwise. In this case I would argue an array/list is most appropriate. It's a homogenous collection of names.

As far as language support - learn it. Remember that JSON is *only* the text, but once in JavaScript (or PHP) objects, there should be appropriate collection searching:

```
var ar = ["a", "b", "c"]
var i = ar.indexOf("b")  // -> 1
var b = ar[i]  
alert(b)                 // -> "b"
```

Note that [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) was introduced in ECMAScript 5th edition. I recommend using a [shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would tend to agree with this, and this is how I've always ended up storing/utilizing the data. I originally posed the question because I have been unable to find suitable documentation to determine whether this _is_ best practice or not.

Comment: @r3mus Practice is practice - and best practice is one of those possibly gray areas ;-) I recommend keeping it as simple and clean and explicit about intent as possible - unless there is a reason to do otherwise; let the [validated] reasons dictate the practical implementation. It's much easier - albeit heartbreaking - to make tidy code messy than it is to clean up/fix a mess :D

Comment: @r3mus That being said, I would personally return `friends: [ {name: ..}, {name: ..} ]` (but still an *array* of friends) because it's more extendible - what if later the id or "nickname" is desired? Even if not here, perhaps in another query? Keeping a common pattern can really help when using a thick-client MVC/MVVM like KO/AngularJS etc. as it can lead to a symmetrical and unified client OM.

Comment: Thanks @user2246674; appreciate your detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following ought to work pretty well:

```
function checkIfFriends(json, friend) {
    return json.friends.indexOf(friend) !== -1;
}
```

You can implement other search functions just as easily:

```
function findFriendsOf(people, friend) {
    var found = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if(people[i].indexOf(friend) !== -1) {
            found.push(people[i]);
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

In general, the best way to store a list of monotyped objects is as an Array. This is what people generally expect it to be stored as and will make other people's lives easier when they have to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not optimum, you could store the elements in a string and use a regex, as in:

```
var src='joe,fred,bob,zebulon';

function hasMember(src,name){
    var RE=new RegExp('(?:^|,)'+name+'(?:,|$)');
    return RE.test(src);
}

src.split(',').forEach(function(name){
   console.log(name+':'+hasMember(src,name));
});
```

which prints:

```
joe:true
fred:true
bob:true
zebulon:true
```

and for console.log('rob:'+hasMember(src,'rob')) prints:

```
rob:false
```

Comment: and what if some of the data has a comma? this is why god gave us JSON...

Comment: Of course, but the OP was looking for alternatives.